# Not to create duplicated tasks with same subject in a custom object

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have a custom object " Policy Transaction", I set a criteria to create tasks on this object. But issue is whenever i am editing the records, Its triggering the criteria and creating duplicated tasks with the same subject.

I want to create a field, which can be ticked, when a task with a particular subject has already been created. and i can add this field in my workflow criteria , not to duplicated the tasks. Can anyone plz suggest how to create such a checkbox field, which can identify a task with a particular subject. ( I tried the formula, WF, PB) but not able to corelated the task object and my custom object. Both are not in a master detail relationship , so i cant create a roll up summary field. plz suggest. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are the criteria for when the Task should be created?  Is it possible that you have the Workflow Rule's **Evaluation Criteria** set to evaluate when the rule is "created, and *every time* it's edited" rather than "created, and any time it's edited *to subsequently meet criteria*" (see screenshot below)?

[image: asdf]

Comment: Ohh thanks Brent, It worked. I was using the second option.

Comment: Huzzah! Glad to hear it, @sourav.